# Problem in Math Writing

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

I have a problem in math writing.

Consider $a_i$ with $1\leq i \leq n$ are some elements over a field.

*My Question:* Which of the following statements is correct?

> A) Let $a_i$'s satisfy the following condition.
>
> B) Let $a_i$'s satisfies the following condition.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This is moreso an English/grammar issue than anything. Since there are multiple $a_i$'s, you would say "let the $a_i$'s satisfy, much as you would say "let the numbers satisfy."

Comment: @EeveeTrainer As far as I understand you mean it is better to write "let the numbers $a_i$'s satisfy". am I right?

Comment: Well, you could just say "let the $a_i$'s satisfy". The second phrase "let the numbers satisfy" was more just to show an analogous phrasing. Since there are multiple $a_i$'s, in this context, you could treat it as a plural noun, much as you would the words "cats," "dogs," or "numbers," and use the corresponding form of the verb ("satisfy" in this case). Ethan Bolker, in his answer below, also gives a few alternative ways of phrasing it that are equally valid.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thanks for your useful comment. I got it.

Comment: Just to clear this up a little: you can say "Let the $a_i$'s satisfy..." or you can say "Let the numbers $a_i$ satisfy...". You definitely can't say "Let the numbers $a_i$'s satisfy...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might say something like

> Suppose the $a_i$ satisfy ...

or

> Suppose $n$ field elements $\{a_i\}$  ( $1 \le i \le n$ )
>   satisfy ...

In any case  the apostrophy s on $a_i$'s feels wrong to me. You do want the plural "satisfy" since you are talking about a sequence of several element**s** (plural).

Comment: I agree that the apostrophe-s feels wrong, but the AMS style guide endorses it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is inappropriate to use an apostrophe-s to pluralize English nouns.  However, the [AMS style guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) (which seems to be an appropriate style guide, given the context) instructs us to use the apostrophe-s to make variable names plural (see page 94).  Hence that part of the construction is appropriate.

That being said, the heart of the question seems to be about the correct conjugation of the verb "to satisfy."  The verb should be conjugated in order to agree with the subject of the sentence.  In this case, the subject of the sentence is "the $a_i$'s", which demands a third person plural conjugation, i.e.

> The $a_i$'s satisfy...

That being said, I agree with Ethan Bolker's assessment that the phrasing is a little awkward, in part because of the apostrophe-s.  An equally readable alternative might be

> The $a_i$ satisfy...

Personally, I might prefer a phrasing which emphasizes the common properties of the field elements in the set.  Hence I would probably write a sentence more like

> Let $k$ be a field and let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{N} \subseteq k$ be a collection which satisfies the condition...

Comment: I like your alternative making the collection of elements an explicit object which you then follow with the singular "satisfies". It does call for more notation, Whether that's a good thing depends on the surrounding context.

Comment: @EthanBolker Indeed.  Context is everything. ;)